Scrapy Spider doesn't scrape all urls in start_urls
I've seen a lot of posts on this but no resolution. I'm obviously doing something wrong but can't figure it out after days of trying.
I've passed in a list of c.2000 urls but when I run the spider by instantiating as below it just crawls a fraction of these urls (never a consistent number) and then exits with no error code. (See final output below). The log mode is debug, I've even tried stepping through it with ipdb.set_trace(), all that happens is in the start_requests for loop it just exits suddenly.
The Spider Code
from typing import List
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError
from twisted.internet.error import TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError

# items = []
class testSpider(Spider):
    name = "test_spider"

    def __init__(self, urls, **kwargs):
        # self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(url).netloc for url in urls]
        self.start_urls = urls
    #     self.rules = (
    #     Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()),  callback='parse', follow=True),
    # )
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                callback=self.parse,
                errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                dont_filter=True,
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
            return {
                "url": response.url,
                "text": soup.get_text(strip=True)
            }
        except:
            print(f"could not crawl {response.url}")
            pass


    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
            # log all failures
            self.logger.error(repr(failure))
            # in case you want to do something special for some errors,
            # you may need the failure's type:
            if failure.check(HttpError):
                # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
                # you can get the non-200 response
                response = failure.value.response
                self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

            elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
                # this is the original request
                request = failure.request
                self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)
            elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
                request = failure.request
                self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)
    # def closed(self, reason):
    #     '''Method to be called after the spider finishes'''
    #     # create datafrane from the global list 'items'
    #     df = pd.DataFrame(items)
    #     # do whatefer operations you want
    #     df.to_csv('test_content.csv', index=False)

Calling the Spider
process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        "FEEDS": {
            "data.csv": {"format": "csv", 'overwrite': True},
        },
        'HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL': True
    })

process.crawl(testSpider, urls=urls)
process.start()

Final Output from the spider
{'downloader/exception_count': 21,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 84576,
 'downloader/request_count': 285,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 285,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5484300,
 'downloader/response_count': 264,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 182,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 54,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/307': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/308': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 21,
 'downloader/response_status_count/410': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 587.32042,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 8, 8, 46, 9, 698716, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 18769899,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 178,
 'item_scraped_count': 181,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 461,
 'log_count/ERROR': 67,
 'log_count/INFO': 20,
 'log_count/WARNING': 3,
 'memusage/max': 177496064,
 'memusage/startup': 135127040,
 'response_received_count': 205,
 'retry/count': 14,
 'retry/max_reached': 7,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 4,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 4,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 285,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 285,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 285,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 285,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 8, 8, 36, 22, 378296, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
2024-04-08 09:46:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Please Help!
I'd expect it to call all the urls passed or at least raise an exception explaining why it didn't finish.
